# Find and replace everything between two placeholders with the contents of a variable

Tags: python, regex, linux, bash, sed

Aloha,
I have been trying to figure out how to replace/insert text strings between two place holders.

```
#start
REPLACE ANYTHING IN HERE
#end
```

Originally I was trying to do this with BASH via sed, but hit a road-block when I tried to pass a variable to sed.

```
sed -n -i '/#start/{p;:a;N;/#end/!ba;s/.*\n/hello\n/};p' file.txt
```

Returns

```
#start
hello
#end
```

but no joy when I try

```
sed -n -i '/#start/{p;:a;N;/#end/!ba;s/.*\n/$replace_var\n/};p' file.txt
```

or

```
sed -n -i "/#start/{p;:a;N;/#end/!ba;s/.*\n/$replace_var\n/};p" file.txt
```

I've been at this for hours, and have searched around but have not found a solution. I'm up to trying in python or another language, or maybe with awk. I'm kind of new in this realm so any useful information would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

This is what I went with in the end.
It's a script that in conjunction with cron, updates my /var/etc/hosts.deny file with the latest published ssh blocklist.

```
import re
import urllib2

hosts_deny = open('/etc/hosts.deny','r+')
hosts_deny_text = hosts_deny.read()

blockedHosts = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.openbl.org/lists/hosts.deny').read()
place = re.compile('(?<=#start)(\r?\n)'
                   '(.*?)'
                   '(?=\r?\n#end)',re.DOTALL)#DOTALL enables '.' to also include
                                             #a new line
hosts_deny_text = re.sub(place, '\n'+ blockedHosts, hosts_deny_text)
hosts_deny.seek(0)
hosts_deny.write(hosts_deny_text)
hosts_deny.close()
```

Comment: Nice first question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what you explain, I can only propose this simple code:

```
import re

ss = '''qslkjqskqsdhf
#start
REPLACE ANYTHING IN HERE
#end
2135468761265
'''

reg = re.compile('(?<=#start)(\r?\n)'
                 '(.*?)'
                 '(?=\r?\n#end)',re.DOTALL)

print ss
print '----'
print reg.sub('\\1Ia orana',ss)
```

result

```
qslkjqskqsdhf
#start
REPLACE ANYTHING IN HERE
#end
2135468761265

----
qslkjqskqsdhf
#start
Ia orana
#end
2135468761265
```

Comment: Based on his question, I think he wants to keep `#start` and `#end` in there (at least his example shows that). That could be achieved, by positive look-behind and look-ahead: `r'(?<=#start\n)(.*?)(?=\n#end)'`.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: … or just by adding them back in, either hard-coded, or by matching them and using `\1` and `\2`.

Comment: Yes I do want the placeholders to remain - I will keep in mind to better define the problem in the future. I thought to do as you suggested and just add them back in by appending them to the "replacement text" but I am intrigued by this look-behind/ahead. I was imagining something like that earlier when I was thinking of how to express to sed what bit of the file I wanted.

Comment: @abarnert Obviously, but regular expression engines provide a comprehensive feature-set for a reason. Look-behind and look-ahead are precisely for situations like these. Matching them, then including them again in the substitution to make up for it is a roundabout approach.

Comment: @Stjepan Thank you. I made your reputation to pass 500 in your more upvoted answer !

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: Yes, but look-behind and look-ahead (a) are vastly different between different regex libraries, (b) can push you into the exponential-backtracking realm (not in this case, but more generally), and (c) can be harder to understand. Besides, matching groups and replacing with `\1` and `\2` is _also_ part of the comprehensive feature-set of regex engines.

Comment: @Jason After the comment of Stjepan, I choosed to write ``'(?<=#start)(\r?\n)'`` because _"look-behind requires fixed-width pattern"_, which means that ``'(?<=#start\r?\n)'`` isn't an authorized syntax. Then, I am obliged to put ``\\1`` in the replacement string to signify that the group(1) , which is the one captured by ``(\r?\n)``, must be written at the place of this \\1

Comment: @abarnert a) I can't think of one. Any examples? b) Because it requires a fixed-length pattern, it can easily check it in linear time while traversing the string itself. All it does is exclude it from the match. In general, though, that's true for all of regular expressions, they are rather inefficient when compared to other methods. But the very idea behind them is to sacrifice efficiency for power, enabling you to do in one line of code what would otherwise take a block. c) Very true, but that's why you learn it, so you can use difficult tools with more ease and reliability in the future.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: But you can do this in one line without lookbehind, as my answer shows. As long as you understand how to use references in replacement, it's trivial: `re.sub(r'(?s)(#start\n).*?\n(#end)',  r'\1hello\n\2', s)`. If eyquem is right, and you still need the refs even if you _do_ use the lookbehind/lookahead, they don't buy you anything at all here. If he's wrong, I still think the refs are more readable and easier to understand, as well as being more concise. So, what power are you gaining?

Comment: @abarnert I was talking about regular expressions in general with the one-liner statement. Yours works fine, you just use references where they aren't needed. It would also work fine to split the entire thing before, between and after the #-strings, replace the middle part and then join them together by those strings. Just introduces some unnecessary steps. Whether they're easy or simple enough, that's up to everyone to decide for themselves. What eyquem said was only in regards to the extra carriage return character, to make it platform-independent. For \n line feeds alone, it works fine.

Comment: @eyquem I had my first success with the solution you proposed, thank you. I will post my finished script when I get it ironed out. I also need to do a bit of research on this usage of the python regex engine. Mahalo again for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 3):

This does seem to do what you want:

```
sed -ie "/#start/,/#end/{/#start/b;/#end/b;s/.*/$replace_var/;}" file.txt
```

The inner `/#start/b`and `/#end/b` skip those lines, otherwise you'd replace them as well.

Comment: This will replace every line between the markers with `$replace_var`, I don't think that is what the OP wants.

Comment: Could you help me read this. I believe in the power of regex, but as it is a rather complex concept I have found my learning curve to be a bit shallow? Many thanks.

Comment: @Jason: The first pair of patterns makes it apply what's in the `{...}` from #start to #end, anything else is just passed through. Within the {}s we branch (b) to the end of the script if the line contains #start or #end so we let those through unchanged too. Anything between the #start and #end line makes it through the s/// to be changed. (That appeared to be what you wanted in your original question (since edited) but you can, of course, make it more selective.)

Comment: @William thank you so much for explaining that, I am going to try with this method as well. I love one liners.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file into a string and then do:

```
sstart = s.split(start)
for i in range(len(s)):
   if i%2 ==1:
      send = sstart[i].split(end)
      for i in range(len(send)):
           if i%2 == 0:
                send[i] = REPLACEMENT
      sstart[i] = send.join()
s = sstart.join()
```

so you're basically walking through the list, cutting out the part that need replacement, and then gluing the parts back together.

Answer (score 0):

With a "dotall" regexp, this is easy. These are easy with Perl, Python, PCRE, etc. For example, in Python:

```
>>> s = '''#start
... REPLACE ANYTHING IN HERE
... #end'''
>>> re.sub(r'(?s)(#start\n).*?\n(#end)',
           r'\1hello\n\2', s)
'#start\nhello\n#end'
```

Obviously matching the start and end lines and replacing them with themselves is overkill, but I decided to keep it general in case you wanted to extend it further.

I used the `(?s)` instead of passing a `re.DOTALL` flag so everything would be self-contained, and you wouldn't have to think about the differences between how Perl, Python, etc. pass flags. But in real life it's usually more readable to use the flags instead of embedding them.

Answer (score 0):

I think `sed` is rather unsuited for this task, I would use awk instead:

```
awk '!f; /#start/ { f=1; print repl } /#end/ { f=0; print }' repl="$replace_var" file.txt
```

The `f` variable is a flag that keeps track of when we're within the markers. `!f` invokes the default block (`{print $0}`) and prints everything outside the markers including the `#start` marker.

#### Testing

Test-file copied from [*eyquem's* answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15147434/1331399):

```
cat << EOF > file.txt
qslkjqskqsdhf
#start
REPLACE ANYTHING IN HERE
#end
2135468761265
EOF
```

Replace inter-marker content with `hello\nhello`:

```
awk '!f; /#start/ { f=1; print repl } /#end/ { f=0; print }' repl="$(printf 'hello\nhello')" file.txt
```

Output:

```
qslkjqskqsdhf
#start
hello
hello
#end
2135468761265
```